# ImportError: cannot import name 'ModelSchema' from 'marshmallow_sqlalchemy'

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am following a tutorial and I came across this error for this: `from marshmallow_sqlalchemy import ModelSchema`

I am unable to find any other references for it online. Any help? Is this tutorial itself outdated? I have been assigned this from someone.

Answer (score 2):

Its deprecated, Now you can use SQLAlchemySchema.

[Read this changelog](https://marshmallow-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html?highlight=ModelSchema#id14)